# Send Ctrl+C to child process when host was created with CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP

Tags: java, c++, windows, process, console

I have 3 processes in a tree: A -> B -> C. A is a host app I don't own that calls `CreateProcess` with `dwCreationFlags = CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` to create process B. B is my service and C is a Java child process that I want to spawn using `CreateProcess` and be able to send Ctrl+C to in order to trigger shutdown hooks.

According to the process creation flags page on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx), the `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flag disables Ctrl+C for all child processes:

> The new process is the root process of a new process group. The process group includes all processes that are descendants of this root process. The process identifier of the new process group is the same as the process identifier, which is returned in the lpProcessInformation parameter. Process groups are used by the GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent function to enable sending a CTRL+BREAK signal to a group of console processes.If this flag is specified, CTRL+C signals will be disabled for all processes within the new process group.

I need a way to bypass this behavior so that I can send Ctrl+C signals to process C. Ctrl+Break can be sent but is not sufficient because this is a Java process and Ctrl+Break doesn't trigger shutdown. I tried creating process C with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` with the assumption that this would allow the new console to receive all signals but Ctrl+C is blocked there as well. Does anyone know if there's some way to override or bypass `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` and cancel this Ctrl+C blocking?

Comment: Have you tried calling `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` to explicitly enable Control-C processing for process B?  (The setting is inheritable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Harry for the suggestion! What worked for me was the below:

```
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(null, false);
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(MyActualHandler, true);
```

It looks like the process group thing works by calling `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(null, true)` and you just have to disable the default handler before adding a real one.